# UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary bypassing imagePickerControllerDidCancel and ignoring allowsEditing

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using an imagePicker with a custom overylay view, which has a button for the photo library, among other things.  I am instantiating it like this:

```
_overlay = [[CameraWithOverlayViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"OverlayView" bundle:nil];
_overlay.delegate = self;

_imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
_imagePicker.delegate = self;
_imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
_imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
_imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
_imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
_imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
_imagePicker.showsCameraControls = NO;
_imagePicker.navigationBarHidden = YES;
_imagePicker.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff;

_imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = _overlay.view;
```

and presenting modally.  The CameraWithOverlayViewController reports overlay button presses back to me via a delegate protocol, which I then use to take the photo, switch to the photo library, or cancel out of the imagePicker.

When the user clicks the photo library button, I am running this:

```
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
```

to bring up the photo library instead of the camera.

Problem one is that when you use a custom camera overlay view, the `imagePicker.allowsEditing` boolean property is bypassed, which means I had to build my own cropping view. But the photo library is sending me to the cropping view even with `imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO` set.

The second problem is that, despite having set myself as the imagePicker's delegate, and implementing the delegate protocol/methods, the cancel button on the photo library's view is not calling `- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker`, so I cannot use that method to put a user back on the camera screen if they cancel from the photo library.

Any insight would be much appreciated!

Comment: put the whole code here, i thing for the first problem you can simple set the allowEditing based on resource type. for second one im not sure why delegate methos not get called.

Comment: added more code. "the whole code" would be 400 lines across three classes, but that should be the relevant bits.